# asp.net: How to detect iOS/Android?

Tags: c#, asp.net, android, ios

I've recently launched a web app written in C#/.net 4.0 making extensive use of jQuery & jQuery UI to give the best possible user experience.

However some users have reported problems when using the site through an iPhone or Android devices.

**What is the best accepted method of detecting both iOS and Android?** so that I can then tweak the UI for each browser.

Comment: Try browsing the [user-agent] tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-agent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generically speaking, you should detect the browser server side, and then render the correct templates/viewport to the browser. Check the user agent string sent to the server, by the browser - iOS generally contains the substring, "iPhone" and Android uses "Android" followed by the version number ("Android 2.2")

Comment: @Andrew-Weir Generically speaking, I would agreed. However my question is after the method of server-side detection, rather than the next stage

Comment: @Peter Bridger: I'm not really sure what you mean by "the method of server-side detection". You're bound to have access to the browser details. Isn't it BrowserCapabilities or HttpBrowserCapabilities? I'm a PHP guy, so unfortuantely my expertise is light in the C# field, however I hope this offers some insight.

Comment: @Andrew-Weir My previous experience of using .net for mobile detection has been spotty. A developer friend used a Codeplex plugin which helped, however this caused strange bugs!

Comment: android default browser contains Linux  and no android, tried on android ver 4.4

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is to try the string

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
```

That will return the word android for android devices so far.
Windows is easy to detect.
Somebody help me with the other fruit.

See more detailed solution at
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34422/Detecting-a-mobile-browser-in-ASP-NET

Comment: You can also use: Request.Headers["User-Agent"]

Comment: Why not simply [`Request.UserAgent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestbase.useragent?view=netframework-4.8)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ASP.NET extension that (apparently, I haven't used it) does all that for you :)

http://51degrees.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -1):

IsMobileDevice does not give correct response on my Android phone.
Here is the code I have used.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">



protected void  TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void  Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
    string s = "Browser Capabilities\n"
        + "Type = " + browser.Type + "\n"
        + "Name = " + browser.Browser + "\n"
        + "Version = " + browser.Version + "\n"
        + "Major Version = " + browser.MajorVersion + "\n"
        + "Minor Version = " + browser.MinorVersion + "\n"
        + "Platform = " + browser.Platform + "\n"
        + " Is MobileDevice ? " + browser.IsMobileDevice + "\n"
        + " screen Height " + browser.ScreenCharactersHeight + "\n"
        + " screen width " + browser.ScreenCharactersWidth + "\n"
        + "Is Beta = " + browser.Beta + "\n"
        + "Is Crawler = " + browser.Crawler + "\n"
        + "Is AOL = " + browser.AOL + "\n"
        + "Is Win16 = " + browser.Win16 + "\n"
        + "Is Win32 = " + browser.Win32 + "\n"
        + "Supports Frames = " + browser.Frames + "\n"
        + "Supports Tables = " + browser.Tables + "\n"
        + "Supports Cookies = " + browser.Cookies + "\n"
        + "Supports VBScript = " + browser.VBScript + "\n"
        + "Supports JavaScript = " +
            browser.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString() + "\n"
        + "Supports Java Applets = " + browser.JavaApplets + "\n"
        + "Supports ActiveX Controls = " + browser.ActiveXControls
              + "\n"
        + "Supports JavaScript Version = " +
            browser["JavaScriptVersion"] + "\n";

    TextBox1.Text = s;
}
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" 
            Width="955px" Rows="22" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
            Text="Find browser" Font-Size="Large" Width="145px" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can try the code at 
 [www.abcd.com.au/browser.aspx](http://www.abcd.com.au/browser.aspx) 
with your mobile phone or other device.