# Decoding device information from user agent

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-agent

Recently, I've add the user agent string when the guests submit the form to the database. There is a report that is generated weekly containing various statistics. I want to add the device and maybe the browser information to the report.

I was pondering that I would create a new database table that would hold all the know user agent strings and have two extra fields, one for the device info, and maybe the browser in the other one. However, I cannot find a site that you can download the strings. Would any one know of a place?

If that can not be done, I was thinking of a .net alternative. How would I go into doing that in .net?

Answer (score 0):

2 ways to do it:

- If you are using ASPNET MVC, you could use the default `this.Request.Browser` within the controller method call (contains quite a lot of info, [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20795571/2952074)),
- You can also use [51Degrees](https://51degrees.codeplex.com/), which has a light and a complete device db to match devices capabilities